# Preferred way of using Bootstrap in Webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js, babeljs

Greetings one and all,

I have been playing around with Bootstrap for Webpack, but I'm at the point of tearing my hair out. I have literally gone through loads of blog articles and they either use the 7 months outdated 'bootstrap-webpack' plugin (which, surprisingly does not work out of the box) or.. They include the Bootstrap files through import 'node_modules/*/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'.

Surely, there must be a cleaner and more efficient way of going about this?

This is my current `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/main.js')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js[x]?$/,
            loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'],
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css']
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass']
        }, {
            test: /\.sass$/,
            loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap'
        },{
            test: /\.less$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less']
        }, {
            test: /\.woff$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=[path][name].[ext]"
        }, {
            test: /\.woff2$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=[path][name].[ext]"
        }, {
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/,
            loader: "file-loader"
        }]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '/js/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '/js/bundle.map',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
    ],
    postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.sass'],
        modulesDirectories: ['src', 'node_modules']
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist'
    }
};
```

I could go and `require('bootstrap')` (with some way of getting jQuery in it to work), but.. I'm curious to what you all think and do.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This may work for you https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack

Comment: Yes, that's the module I mentioned that hasn't been updated in months.

Comment: Sorry then. I've no idea as of now.

Comment: And even now, 5 months later, there is still no good answer on the internet :(

Comment: Yeah it's actually one of the reasons why we haven't fully adopted Webpack yet, too many 'simple and small' issues like this which can make actual development past setup pretty annoying.

Comment: You can include jquery like this in your webpack config under the plugin section:

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })

and then in your js file you can require('jquery/dist/jquery.min'); and require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');

Comment: This is how I have been including bootstrap 4. Not sure if it is the best way https://gist.github.com/vishim/9c3e1b06a8f513c923e5187490d8f917

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way, but following work for me well with `vue.js` webapp. You can see the working code [here](https://github.com/mimani/vue-example).

I have included files required by bootstrap in [index.html](https://github.com/mimani/vue-example/blob/master/index.html) like this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hey</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script  href="/static/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
```

And this works, you can execute the repo. Why I went this way was I had to [customise](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/) some config in [bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) so I had to change the variables file and build the code of bootstrap which outputted me `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css`files, which I am using here.

---

There is an alternative way suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40864747/1610034) by using the npm package and a webpack customisation.

First install bootstrap in your project:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5
```

And make sure you can use sass-loader in your components:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

now go to your webpack config file and add a sassLoader object with the following:

```
sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [
        path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/'),
    ],
},
```

`projectRoot` should just point to where you can navigate to `node_packages` from, in my case this is: `path.resolve(__dirname, '../')`

Now you can use bootstrap directly in your .vue files and webpack will compile it for you when you add the following:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "bootstrap";
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the indepth answer I was looking for! Heres' to hoping they will get rid of jQuery sooner than later ;)  
I have to wait half an hour before I can give the bounty, but it is coming :)

Comment: This is going to get me out of a spot, but shouldn't I be using webpack to bundle my bootstrap? What's the point of having webpack if I'm linking to scripts from my index.html?

Comment: @user1585345: I was having the same thought (and the same problem to start with)

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using [bootstrap-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader). You add a config file (`.bootstraprc` in your root folder) where you can exclude the bootstrap elements you don't want and tell where your `variables.scss` and `bootstrap.overrides.scss` are. Define you SCSS variables, do your overrides, add your webpack entry and get on with your life.

Answer (score 1):

I use webpack to build bootstrap directly from .less and .scss files. This allows customizing bootstrap by overriding the source in .less/.scss and still get all the benefits of webpack.

Your code is missing an entry point for any .css/.less/.scss files. You need to include an entry point for the compiled css files. For this entry point, I declare an array with `const` and then include paths inside the array to the source files I want webpack to compile.

Currently, I'm using bootstrap 3 with a base custom template and also a 2nd custom theme. The base template uses bootstrap .less file styling and it has specific source overrides written in .less files.

The 2nd custom theme uses .sass file styling and has similar overrides to bootstrap's base written in .scss files.  So, I need to try to optimize all this styling for production (currently coming in about 400kb but that's a little heavy because we choose to avoid CDN's due to targeting use in China).

Below is a reference webpack.config.js which works to build from .less/.scss/.css files, and also does a few other things like build typescript modules and uses Babel for converting es6/typescript to browser compatible javascript.  The output ultimately ends up in my `/static/dist` folder.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// plugins
const ForkTsCheckerNotifierWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-notifier-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');


// take debug mode from the environment
const debug = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production');
// Development asset host (webpack dev server)
const publicHost = debug ? 'http://localhost:9001' : '';
const rootAssetPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');


const manifestOptions = {
    publicPath: `${publicHost}/static/dist/`,
  };

const babelLoader = {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env'
    ]
  }
};

const app_css = [
    // specific order generally matters
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bootstrap-template1', 'assets', 'css', 'fonts', 'Roboto', 'css', 'fonts.css'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'font-awesome', 'css', 'font-awesome.css'),
    // This is bootstrap 3.3.7 base styling writtin in .less
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bootstrap-template1', 'assets',  'less', '_main_full', 'bootstrap.less'),
    // bootstrap theme in .scss -> src\bp\folder\theme\src\scss\styles.scss
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bp', 'folder', 'theme', 'src', 'scss', 'styles.scss'),
    // back to .less -> 'src/bootstrap-template1/assets/less/_main_full/core.less',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bootstrap-template1', 'assets', 'less', '_main_full', 'core.less'),
    // 'src/bootstrap-template1/assets/less/_main_full/components.less',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bootstrap-template1', 'assets', 'less', '_main_full', 'components.less'),
    //'src/bootstrap-template1/assets/less/_main_full/colors.less',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bootstrap-template1', 'assets', 'less', '_main_full', 'colors.less'),
    // <!-- syntax highlighting in .css --> src/bp/folder/static/css/pygments.css
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bp', 'folder', 'static', 'css', 'pygments.css'),
    // <!-- lato/ptsans font we want to serve locally --> src/fonts/googlefonts.css'
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'fonts', 'googlefonts.css'),
    // a .css style -> 'src/bp/appbase/styles/md_table_generator.css'
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'bp', 'appbase', 'styles', 'md_table_generator.css'),
    // another .css style -> hopscotch 'src/libs/hopscotch/dist/css/hopscotch.min.css'
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'libs', 'hopscotch', 'dist', 'css', 'hopscotch.min.css'),
    //LAST final custom snippet styles to ensure they take priority 'src/css/style.css',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'css', 'style.css')
];

const vendor_js = [
    //'core-js',
    'whatwg-fetch',
];

const app_js = [
    // a typescript file! :)
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'typescript', 'libs', 'md-table', 'src', 'extension.ts'),
    // base bootstrap 3.3.7 javascript
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'bootstrap', 'dist', 'js', 'bootstrap.js'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'app.js'),
    // src/bootstrap-template1/assets/js/plugins/forms/styling/uniform.min.js'
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@imanov', 'jquery.uniform', 'src', 'js', 'jquery.uniform.js'),
    // src/bootstrap-template1/assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment.min.js'
];

function recursiveIssuer(m) {
  if (m.issuer) {
    return recursiveIssuer(m.issuer);
  } else if (m.name) {
    return m.name;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

module.exports = {
    context: process.cwd(), // to automatically find tsconfig.json
    // context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app_css,
        vendor_js,
        app_js,
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: `${publicHost}/static/dist/`,
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash:7].js',
        filename: '[name].[hash:7].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js",".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css"],
        alias: {
            jquery$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'jquery', 'dist', 'jquery.js'),
        }
    },
    target: "web",
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        // this devserver proxies all requests to my python development server except 
        // webpack compiled files in the `/static/dist` folder 
        clientLogLevel: 'warning',
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
        publicPath: 'dist',
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
        watchContentBase: true,
        port: 9001,
        proxy: {
            '!(/dist/**/**.*)': {
                target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
            },
        },
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({})],
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            appStyles: {
              name: 'app',
              // https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#extracting-css-based-on-entry
              test: (m, c, entry = 'app') =>
                m.constructor.name === 'CssModule' && recursiveIssuer(m) === entry,
              chunks: 'all',
              enforce: true,
            },
          },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery'
        }),
        // Strip all locales from moment.js except "zh-cn"
        // ("en" is built into Moment and can’t be removed)
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: ['zh-cn'],
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            tslint: true, useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerNotifierWebpackPlugin({ title: 'TypeScript', excludeWarnings: false }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[hash:7].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].[hash:7].css',
            moduleFilename: ({ name }) => `${name.replace('/js/', '/css/')}.[hash:7].css`
        }),
         new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /\.optimize\.css$/g,
            cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
            cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
            preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
            },
            canPrint: true
        }),
        new ManifestPlugin({
            ...manifestOptions
        }),
    ].concat(debug ? [] : [
        // production webpack plugins go here
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
            }
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            async: false,
            useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
            memoryLimit: 2048
        }),
    ]),
    module: {
        rules: [
                {
                // jinja/nunjucks templates
                test: /\.jinja2$/,
                loader: 'jinja-loader',
                query: {
                    root:'../templates'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    babelLoader,
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options:
                            {   // disable type checker - we will use it in
                                // fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
                                transpileOnly: true
                            }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    babelLoader
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html|jinja2)$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sc|sa|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                          hmr: debug,
                            // only use if hmr is not working correctly
                          // reloadAll: true,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                          hmr: debug,
                            // only use if hmr is not working correctly
                          // reloadAll: true,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|ico)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[hash:7].[ext]',
                            context: rootAssetPath
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png)$/i,
                loader: 'responsive-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[path][name].[hash:7].[ext]',
                    adapter: require('responsive-loader/sharp'),
                    context: rootAssetPath
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                 loader:'url-loader',
                 options:{
                    limit: 10000,
                    mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
                    // name: ('fonts/[path][name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
                    name: ('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
                 }
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                use:[
                    { loader: "expose-loader", options:"$" },
                    { loader: "expose-loader", options:"jQuery" },
                    { loader: "expose-loader", options:"jquery" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
};
```