# How can I use Bootstrap while using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have a common file setup like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

That loads the jQuery and Bootstrap JS onto the page, but not the CSS. Node modules aren't in a public folder so I can't just point at the CSS file sitting there, without moving where node modules install, which is kinda hacky.

Meanwhile it's also complaining `jQuery` is not defined.

I tried using the lib mentioned at [Preferred way of using Bootstrap in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131705/preferred-way-of-using-bootstrap-in-webpack) but the error changed to `Cannot find module "bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot"` and it looked like the CSS wasn't there anyway. Much confusion.

I also get a number of related errors like this when webpack runs:

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
Module parse failed: /Users/dstein/Repositories/readthru/node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
```

Comment: you need font loaded. Check file loader or URL loader.

Comment: @Dave Stein
Did you find the answer you were looking for?