# using bootstrap with vue webapp : How to customise

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using [bootstrap-4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) in my Vue webapp, But I am not able to customise this as is explained [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/).

I have my **index.html** which uses [Bootstrap CDN](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#bootstrap-cdn), like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/custom.scss" type="text/x-scss">  ==> where I am overwriting variable
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="/dist/client-vendor-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/client-bundle.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried changing the order of `custom.scss` and `bootstrap.css` in **index.html** as well.

Following is **custom.scss**, where I am overwriting variables:

```
$body-bg:    #f5f5f5;
$body-color: #f5f5f5;
$enable-flex: true;
```

But this is not working.

I also tried importing this in my app component, like following:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import 'custom.scss';

  // Following also did not work
  $body-bg: #333;
  $body-color: #999;  
</style>
```

How do I overwrite these variable to customise my webapp.

Comment: Did you tried to reverse order ? first include bootstrap file, then custom.css ? And btw did you re-compile code after you edit .scss file ?

Comment: Yes, as tried changing the order, and also recompiled the code.

Comment: Btw why you are incuding custom.scss file ? why you didn't include compiled .css file ?

Comment: @Belmin You mean compiled .css files of bootstrap or custom.scss?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the `cdn` use the [npm version](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#package-managers) where you get access to bootstrap's `.scss` files and compile it with your custom `.scss` so you can overwrite those values.

Comment: I mean compiled custom.scss -> custom.css, because I'm not sure does browser could read native .scss files

Comment: @Belmin, @craig_h See updated question, I also tried to change `_custom.css` in bootstrap and compile it, this also not working, that is actually strange.

Comment: I was refering to this line of code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/custom.scss" type="text/x-scss">` for me it's strange to try to load .scss file as stylesheet

Comment: @craig_h Sorry, I did some mistake, compiling bootstrap code worked, I dont think customising is possible via CDN.

Comment: its not as your loading css - you can only override it. I added an answer below which will allow you to customise your output as it's a SASS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this a lot cleaner by using the npm package and a webpack customisation.

If you first install bootstrap in your project:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5
```

and make sure you can use sass-loader in your components:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev
```

now go to your webpack config file and add a `sassLoader` object with the following:

```
sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [
        path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/'),
    ],
},
```

`projectRoot` should just point to where you can navigate to `node_packages` from, in my case this is: `path.resolve(__dirname, '../')`

Now you can use bootstrap directly in your `.vue` files and webpack will compile it for you when you add the following:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "bootstrap";
</style>
```

To customise it I'd recommend pulling in the bootstrap `_variables` first and then you can reference everything like normal, i.e.

```
@import "_variables";

// example customisation - I'd recommend importing a file here to store them all
$body-bg: $gray-dark;

// just place all your customisation work above the below import of bootstrap
@import "bootstrap";
```

This will mean you need to remove any CDN CSS versions or they could overwrite things, but you should now be able to fully customise bootstrap.

As another benefit this method allows you to strip out any bootstrap components you are not using. To do so rather than `@import "bootstrap";` which is the entire bootstrap library, instead navigate to that file, i.e. `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss` and then copy across the @import's you actually want. Essentially optimising your project...

Answer (score 1):

I tried following approach which worked:

- cloned the bootstrap [repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)
- modified [_custom.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_custom.scss) in this directory.
- ran `npm install`
- ran `grunt dist` as is in [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup)
- copied generated bootstrap css and js files from here in my **index.html**

so my **index.html** has following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script href="/static/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

As of now, I don't think customising is possible when using CDN link of bootstrap.