# What extra features does bootstrap-loader provide?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

(disclaimer:  I am very much a node/js/npm newbie.  and I most certainly am not aiming to disrespect the hard work done by the bootstrap-loader developers).

I come from a Django background, with hand-written html and js.  Jquery.  I finally bit the bullet and decided to use npm & webpack to enable Vue and generally improve my front end.

Everything went fairly well until bootstrap.  After a fair bit of effort, I got bootstrap4 working with https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-loader.

But when I went back a little later, **bootstrap-loader** had been updated, and did not work with Webpack 1, anymore.  I tried, but failed to get it to work.

There's a similar SO question out here:  [Preferred way of using Bootstrap in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131705/preferred-way-of-using-bootstrap-in-webpack).  And, yes, apparently folks are having problems.

But, there are also postings about just integrating to bootstrap "manually", i.e. w.o. bootstrap-loader.  For example, https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-use-webpack-with-react-and-bootstrap-b94d33765970 and http://blog.theodybrothers.com/2015/07/how-to-use-bootstrap-css-only-and.html.

Now, the stuff that I have to do to use bootstrap without bootstrap-loader seem to end up being:

1. install modules like the sass preprocessors.
2. adjust webpack's config to point the correct loaders at the appropriate resources.
3. adjust for bootstrap wanting to see a global jQuery.  Tether.

But, 1, 2 and 3 end up being pretty much the same whether I roll my own or whether I use bootstrap-loader.  In fact, having gone through the hard work of configuring webpack to work with bootstrap-loader, the manual method hardly involved any effort at all.

**So, what does a specialized module like bootstrap-loader do extra compared to doing this manually?**

Better bundling and chunking of bootstrap into fewer http requests?  Testing?  Better support for customizing bootstrap's base scss assets?  Fonts?

Again, I confess, I am a bit new to this webpack thing, and my use case is a bit unorthodox so I apologize if I missed something obvious to everyone else (I've also had this type of question - *why go for an extra dependency?* - on Django packages and Chef cookbooks, but I understand those stacks better).