# How to include Bootstrap into Vue Js webpack template?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, vue.js

I've installed my vue.js webpack environment using [CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). I am new to webpack and I don't know how to add bootstrap both css and js into that.

Can anyone please tell me the step by step process of this?

Thank You.

Comment: Or maybe [Preferred way of using Bootstrap in Webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42358091/392102)

Comment: Ya, this is what I was looing for. I also added that answer here. @RoyJ